# Sort results based on order of entries in the WHERE's IN clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a query

```
 select * 
 from qtable 
 where qid in (15,555,2,3,4,5,36,27,18,9)
```

here qid is the primary key.

I get the following results sorted out by qid as it is the primary key but my requirement is to get the results as mentioned in the in (15, 555, 2, 3, 4, 5, 36, 27, 18, 9) statement.

Is there a way to unsort the records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 select qtable.* 
 from qtable join (values (15),(55),(2),(3),(4))a(id)
 on a.Id = qtable.qID
```

Comment: why are the qid's put in circle braces?

Comment: Because each indicates a row.

Comment: @Venkat, I'll add that without `ORDER BY` the ordering of results is plan-dependent. This may work today but not tomorrow. In short [order by is required](https://www.dbdelta.com/order-by-is-required/) when you need results in a particular order.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server and other ANSI SQL compliant database require an `ORDER BY` clause to return data in a particular order. One approach is to use a row constructor that includes the desired sequence:

```
SELECT qtable.* 
FROM qtable 
JOIN (VALUES
     (1, 15)
    ,(2, 555)
    ,(3, 2)
    ,(4, 3)
    ,(5, 4)
    ,(6, 5)
    ,(7, 36)
    ,(8, 27)
    ,(9, 18)
    ,(10, 9)
    ) AS list(seq, value) ON qtable.quid = list.qid
ORDER BY list.seq;
```

A similar technique can be used for variable list of values passed as a table-valued parameter or table variable:

```
DECLARE @list TABLE (
      seq int
    , qid int);

INSERT INTO @list VALUES
     (1, 15)
    ,(2, 555)
    ,(3, 2)
    ,(4, 3)
    ,(5, 4)
    ,(6, 5)
    ,(7, 36)
    ,(8, 27)
    ,(9, 18)
    ,(10, 9);

SELECT qtable.* 
FROM qtable 
JOIN @list AS list ON qtable.quid = list.qid
ORDER BY list.seq;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
select qid,case when qid = 15 then 1
when qid = 555 then 2
when qid = 2 then 3
when qid = 3 then 4
when qid = 4 then 5
when qid = 5 then 6
when qid = 36 then 7
when qid = 27 then 8
when qid = 18 then 9
when qid = 9 then 10
end as qidflag



 from qtable where qid in (15,555,2,3,4,5,36,27,18,9)

 order by qidflag
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option where you can pass the desired ID/Sequence as a delimited string.

The Sequence will be maintained.

**Example**

```
Declare @List varchar(max)='15,555,2,3,4,5,36,27,18,9'

Select A.* 
 From  qtable A
 Join (
        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
              ,RetVal = v.value('(./text())[1]', 'int')
        From  (values (convert(xml,'<x>' + replace(@List,',','</x><x>')+'</x>'))) x(n)
        Cross Apply n.nodes('x') node(v)
      ) B on A.quid = B.RetVal
 Order By B.RetSeq
```

**If it Helps - the sub-query Returns**

```
RetSeq  RetVal
1       15
2       555
3       2
4       3
5       4
6       5
7       36
8       27
9       18
10      9
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use something similar to the following:

```
DECLARE @qidList TABLE (sort INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), qid INT);
INSERT @qidList VALUES
(15),
(555),
(2),
(3),
(4),
(5),
(36),
(27),
(18),
(9);


select qtable.* 
from qtable
join @qidList list on list.qid=qtable.qid
order by list.sort;
```